# Check if a URL will redirect the parent page once its loaded into an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iframe, redirect

I am wondering if there is a simple way to test a URL before I load it into an iFrame to see if it will try to redirect the parent page (e.g. the iframed page does not want to be iframed - nyt, google, MS).

If it will redirect the parent page I will not load it into the iFrame and then give the user the option to navigate to the URL on their own. This seems like it should be less intrusive and easier than mucking with `onbeforeunload` or similar methods.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt it is possible. I suggest not to open **any** URLs that are not yours into iframes in the first place, and then you won't have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Not really.

Long Answer: Knowing whether or not a URL is going to resolve to a page that does not want to be in an iFrame requires knowing, before you load it, whether the page has a script which causes it to pop out of the iframe and into a new tab/window.
If you had a conclusive list of which pages *do* have such functionality, then it would just be a matter of checking if the link you're trying to open is in that list and *then* deciding what to do with it.